# Is this a valid h:commandButton operation?

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

My `beanLogIn` class is requestedScoped. What I wanted to do is, if the user information was valid, `oncomplete` or immediately send the `boolean validUser (pessoaValida)` to `beanHome`. But this doesn't work. Why? Is the code wrong or is the session just closed before completion?

```
 <h:commandButton value="Log In" action="#{beanLogIn.verificarLogIn()}" immediate="#      
 {beanHome.verificarUsuario(beanLogIn.pessoaValida)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work.

```
 <h:commandButton value="Log In" action="#{beanLogIn.validateUser()}" />

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BeanLogin {

    public String validateUser {
        // perform your validation logic
        return "beanHome?faces-redirect=true"; // here you should mention beanHome URL
    }

}
```